# Laravel 5.2 - Storing Data in MySQL DB with Homestead/Virtualbox/Vagrant

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, homestead

I am running a Vagrant/VirtualBox/Homestead local development system on my Mac machine, and I am trying to get a Laravel 5.2 project up and running.  The site is loading fine, but when I try to set up data entry into the DB with forms, the data is not being recorded in my db.

As far as I can see this should work.  Here is some code:

in UserController.php:

```
public function store() {
        $input = Request::all();

        $user = new User;
        $user->email = $input['email'];


        return redirect('/contact');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/', 'UserController@store');
```

Form:

```
                <form method="POST" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="subscribe">


                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />

                    <ul class="buttons">
                        <li><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="button special"></li>
                    </ul>


                </form>
```

No errors are being thrown, but the data is not being stored in my Homestead DB on my local machine.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just add $user->save() after $user->email. You forgot to save the new entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually inserting anything in your db. Lets assume 'MyModel' is your model, add this line `MyModel::create($user);`, your store function inside the controller should be something like this:

```
public function store() {
        $input = Request::all();

        $user = new User;
        $user->email = $input['email'];

        MyModel::create($user);

        return redirect('/contact');
    }
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$user->save();` after  `$user->email = $input['email'];` line.